# Delete text before comma in a delimited field

Tags: awk, delimiter

I have a pipe delimited file where I want to remove all text before a comma in field 9.

Example line:

```
www.upstate.edu|upadhyap|Prashant K Upadhyaya, MD||General Surgery|http://www.upstate.edu/hospital/providers/doctors/?docID=upadhyap|Patricia J. Numann Center for Breast, Endocrine & Plastic Surgery|Upstate Specialty Services at Harrison Center|Suite D, 550 Harrison Street||Syracuse|NY|13202|
```

so the targeted field is:   `|Suite D, 550 Harrison Street|`

and I want it to look like: `|550 Harrison Street|`

So far what I have tried has either deleted information from other fields (usually the name in field 3) or has had no effect.

The .awk script I have been trying to write looks like this:

```
mv $1 $1.bak4 
cat $1.bak4 | awk -F "|" '{
    gsub(/*,/,"", $9);
    print $0
}'  > $1
```

Comment: It's unclear what the environment is. Is this a shell script? `bash` or `sh`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern argument to `gsub` is a regex not a glob. Your <kbd>*</kbd> isn't matching what you expect it to. You want `/.*,/` there. You are also going to need to `OFS` to <kbd>|</kbd> to keep that delimiter.

```
mv $1 $1.bak4 
awk 'BEGIN{ FS = OFS = "|" }{ gsub(/.*,/,"",$9) } 1' $1.bak4 > $1
```

I also replaced the verbose print line you had with a true pattern (`1`) that uses the fact that the default action is print.

Comment: Or it could be like this `awk 'BEGIN{ FS = OFS = "|" }{ sub(/.*, */,"",$9) } 1'` if you want to remove the leading spaces.